# Getting Event data within a CustomView after setRange is called

Tags: fullcalendar

So I'm trying to build my own custom view for a month's worth of data (based on the "agenda-views.html' example) and I've been able to create a custom View class which adds itself as a button on the list of .. buttons.

When I click on that button (MyView), its setRange is called so I know the range of Events to display. 
The View's renderEvents is called but is passed *all* of the Events that the Calendar knows about, so I have a two parter question:

(a) Is there a way I can use existing code to do the equivalent of: "given this range, give me all of the Events fullCalendar knows about"?
- or -
(b) Do I use an XHR here to pull back the data for the given range (now that I know what it is is) and Render it

I'd rather do (a) as it's more efficient (less requests etc) but I'm finding myself swamped in code and, after reading through quite a lot it haven't really found a method that says 'Get all events for this range'.

Alternatively, am I missing something? How does renderEvents know what the current range is and then render them? Or, should I be using renderSelection, which doesn't seem to get called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your events as a [json feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/), when the URL is called it will pass the start and end dates for the current view. In your function/method/action you then retrieve your events for the given dates and return them.

Comment: Yeah; I realised that my CustomView (when it inherits from the standard View) includes the "start" and "end" Moment variables which are set by the view's setRange method. Once these are set, I can loop through the events passed into renderEvents and find the ones within that range. Thanks!